# Calculate no of days between two latest dates for each ID column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datediff

I have a table like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Submitted Date`**</kbd>
<kbd>`00001`</kbd><kbd>`20-JUL-2018`</kbd>   
<kbd>`00001`</kbd><kbd>`17-MAR-2017`</kbd>   
<kbd>`00001`</kbd><kbd>`20-JUN-2019`</kbd>   
<kbd>`00002`</kbd><kbd>`20-JUL-2018`</kbd>   
<kbd>`00002`</kbd><kbd>`22-AUG-2018`</kbd>   
<kbd>`00002`</kbd><kbd>`23-APR-2019`</kbd>

I want to calculate the no of days between latest two Submitted Date for each ID.

Like for **ID = 00001** , the no of days should be **20-JUN-2019 - 20-JUL-2018**.

> I am using Oracle 11G.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Oracle version? ...

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (submitted_date - prev_sd) as day_diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(submitted_date) over (partition by id order by submitted_date) as prev_sd,
             lead(submitted_date) over (partition by id order by submitted_date) as next_sd
      from t
     ) t
where next_sd is null;
```

This method avoids any aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, 
MAX(SUBMITTED_DATE - PREV_SUBMITTED_DATE) AS DIFF
FROM
(SELECT ID, SUBMITTED_DATE,  
LAG(SUBMITTED_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUBMITTED_DATE) AS PREV_SUBMITTED_DATE
FROM
(SELECT ID, SUBMITTED_DATE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUBMITTED_DATE DESC) AS RN
FROM TABLE)
WHERE RN <= 2)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Or

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DIFF) AS DIFF FROM
(SELECT ID,
NTH_VALUE(SUBMITTED_DATE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUBMITTED_DATE DESC) -  
NTH_VALUE(SUBMITTED_DATE,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUBMITTED_DATE DESC) AS DIFF
FROM TABLE)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation; you can find the previous date for each row, and also assign a ranking based on the date order:

```
select id, submitted_date,  
  lag(submitted_date) over (partition by id order by submitted_date) as previous_date,
  dense_rank() over (partition by id order by submitted_date desc) as rnk
from your_table;
ID    SUBMITTED_DATE PREVIOUS_DATE        RNK
----- -------------- ------------- ----------
00001 2017-03-17                            3
00001 2018-07-20     2017-03-17             2
00001 2019-06-20     2018-07-20             1
00002 2018-07-20                            3
00002 2018-08-22     2018-07-20             2
00002 2019-04-23     2018-08-22             1
```

And then use that as an inline view to only get the latest date - which is ranked first:

```
select id, submitted_date, previous_date,
  submitted_date - previous_date as diff
from
(
  select id, submitted_date,  
    lag(submitted_date) over (partition by id order by submitted_date) as previous_date,
    dense_rank() over (partition by id order by submitted_date desc) as rnk
  from your_table
)
where rnk = 1;

ID    SUBMITTED_DATE PREVIOUS_DATE       DIFF
----- -------------- ------------- ----------
00001 2019-06-20     2018-07-20           335
00002 2019-04-23     2018-08-22           244
```